# Can a Windows RT machine be made to mirror to an AirPlay receiver such as an AppleTV?

Tags: windows-8, airplay

Can I get an App or otherwise modify an ARM-based Windows 8 Windows RT system to be able to mirror it's screen via AirPlay to AppleTV or similar receiver?

I'm not looking for a Windows-equivalent functionality to mirror a screen; I specifically want to use the AirPlay protocol to do this to take advantage of existing AppleTV/AirServer setups located on the campus where I work. I know I could do this on a full Windows 8 x86 system using AirParrot or similar software, but I want to know if I can get something to work for ARM-based Windows RT.

Comment: Ouch! Come back in 6-12 months time! Then we will see who and what is supporting RT. ;)

Comment: @JulianKnight that's my expectation exactly. Give it six months and hopefully _someone_ has a solution by then. I don't have a tablet right now to play with, but if I did I would want to use AirPlay here. When we end up getting one or two down the road I want the answer for this ready and waiting.

Comment: Yep, it's going to be an interesting year for mobile devices. I still don't trust MS though and wonder just how long they will really support RT.

Comment: I think RT is part of their long-term strategy, so don't second-guess them just yet. Even Zune took a long time to die.

Comment: This would depend on if Apple releases a Metro UI iTunes application.

Comment: @Ramhound iTunes has _nothing_ to do with it. There are already several systems (AirParrot, AirServer, AeroHive, etc) that take advantage of the AirPlay protocol without making any use of iTunes.

Comment: Careful... [WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) is completely different to [Windows RT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT).

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - You are the only one talking about WinRT.

Comment: @Ramhound: that's 'cos I corrected it.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you're after?  airserver.

http://www.appletvhacks.net/2012/05/09/airserver-airplay-mirroring-for-your-mac-or-windows-pc-you-heard-me-review/

I've also seen some open source software that can act as an airplay server.  Someone reverse engineered the protocols.  It was not complete last I looked.

Comment: No. It's going the wrong direction, and is not supported on RT. Looking for something more like AirParrot, but that's also WinRT capable.